# ArrayList within an array of lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How do I go about creating a 3-dimensional array of lists which holds an ArrayList in each element?

I need the outer object, the array itself, to be "static" and can't use an arraylist due to it's tendency to resize itself.
The inner lists at each element are expected to resize regularly which is why I need the arraylist.

The code below appears correct, in theory. However, when run it yields a null pointer exception.

```java
public List<ArrayList<Algae>>[][][] populate(int val, int size) {
    List<ArrayList<Algae>>[][][] pond = new List[size][size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                pond[i][j][k].add(new ArrayList<Algae>(2));
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < val; c++) {
                    pond[i][j][k].get(0).add(new Algae());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pond;
}
```

Comment: An ArrayList should not resize itself randomly, but only when you put items into the list. If elements are themselves ArrayList's, the outer ArrayList will not resize itself if you change one of the inner ArrayList's. But you can use just a normal array if you know the exact size.

Comment: You're right, that's way simpler and solved my problem. Thanks NomadMaker :)

Comment: Maybe try showing everybody the Algae Class

Comment: The problem has been solved using the method stated by NomadMaker. Also, the Algae class is just a simple object/type added to the ArrayList and has no effect on how the ArrayLists themselves function.

Answer (score 0):

To fix NPE, you should have initialize the innermost item of the array:

```java
                for(int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                {
                    pond[i][j][k] = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Algae>>(2);
                    pond[i][j][k].add(new ArrayList<Algae>());
                }
```